# check if value explode in array is duplicated with another explode value

Tags: php, arrays

hello try to find the duplicated value in array i have array like that

```
$array = array('1%2','3%4','1%2',1%3);
```

so i want to find duplicated `2` after `%` so i used explode inside foreach

```
foreach($array as $value){
   $s = explode('%',$value);
   if($s[1] == $s[1]){
    echo 'there are duplicated 2';
   }
}
```

so i want `$s[1]` check if value after `%` in array is duplicated
is there anyway to do that

Comment: Store your exploded check values in an array, then check future values against that array with `in_array`

Comment: i dont understand how in_array function gonna help me to display duplicated value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to collect the right side values as you loop through them and check for duplicates.  I am accessing the strings' right side values via their "offset" `[2]`.  When found, you can exit the loop with a `break`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/02ceaf55a8b7d113b8483260c9900cd9299970c3))

```
$array=['1%2','3%4','1%2','1%3'];
$kept=[];
foreach($array as $i=>$v){
    if(in_array($v[2],$kept)){
        echo "Element (index $i) containing $v has duplicate right side value.";
        break;
    }
    $kept[]=$v[2];
}
```

Output:

```
Element (index 2) containing 1%2 has duplicate right side value.
```

---

If you want to search for all element that end with `%2`, you can use `preg_grep()`.

Code:

```
$search=2;
$array=['1%2','1%3','1%4','3%2','5%2'];
var_export(preg_grep("/%{$search}$/",$array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1%2',
  3 => '3%2',
  4 => '5%2',
)
```

---

Or without regex, it will require more function calls:

```
$search=2;
$array=['21%2','1%3','2%22','1%4','3%21','5%2'];
var_export(array_filter($array,function($v)use($search){return strpos($v,"%$search")+2===strlen($v);}));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '21%2',
  5 => '5%2',
)
```

---

...[deep breath]  Here is attempted answer #4...

Code:

```
$array=['1%2','1%3','1%4','3%2','5%2'];
foreach($array as $v){
    $grouped[explode('%',$v)[1]][]=$v;  // use right side number as key
}
var_export($grouped);
```

Output:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '1%2',
    1 => '3%2',
    2 => '5%2',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '1%3',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => '1%4',
  ),
)
```

---

If you want to count the right side values in the array:

```
$array=['1%2','1%3','1%4','3%2','5%2'];
$array=preg_replace('/\d+%/','',$array);  // strip the left-size and % from elements
var_export(array_count_values($array));  // count occurrences
```

Output:

```
// [right side values] => [counts]
array (
  2 => 3,
  3 => 1,
  4 => 1,
)
```

Comment: hello, thanks, but $v[2] return 1%2 but i need to search for the number after % and check if it's duplicated lets say my array like that $a = array('1%2','1%3','1%4','3%2','5%2'); i want my output to be , there are 3 duplicated value 1%2 , 3%2 and 5%2

Comment: I have added a search variable to my latest methods.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: hello thank you but 2 is just an example i meant to check every number after % if has duplicated mean a=array('1%3','2%4','3%3','5%4','1%6','3%2'); i want the output to be like there are 2 duplicated value of number 3 and there are 2 duplicated value of number 4 , that's what i want, value after % it's custom value user can add any number

Comment: I don't think I have ever chased around a question like this before.  Please tell me that in my battery of answers is the solution that you are looking for.  If not, please post a relevant input and desired output in the form of an edit on your question.

Comment: At this point, I don't know what the correct answer is (and neither will future SO readers) Please do us all the favor of clarifying what your desired output is.

Comment: the last one is my answer im sorry but im not very good in english